# How to prove that a perfectly secure cryptographic protocol is not possible in a given scenario?

Tags: algorithm-design

This question was inspired from the discussion related to [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/141484/how-to-distribute-software-with-one-time-installation-key-in-complete-offline/) on security StackExchange.
Now I was wondering given a scenario, is there a general approach to prove that a cryptographic protocol is possible/not possible for a the constraints provided? All I could think of was, trial and error. Develop a protocol, see if you can break it and if not, then you have your answer.

Comment: Schneier's Law (or one of them?) is 'any amateur can design a cipher he himself can't break' -- what matters is whether it can be broken by someone _who knows how to break ciphers_. The same principle applies to security systems more generally.